# "Lenient" regex matching of similar characters in C#/.Net

Tags: .net, regex, unicode

Is there a way to get .Net to positively match strings, even if some characters are not exactly the same? Examples of characters that should be considered to be similar could be: 'a'/'á' and 'í'/'i'. The Chrome browser find-as-you-type recognizes these characters as being equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this blog post](http://www.siao2.com/2005/02/19/376617.aspx) by Michael Kaplan. The code here uses standard .NET class library methods for

1. Normalising Unicode strings, in this case, using a "composite" normalisation form which ensures that a character like *á* is represented by separate code points for *a* and its diacritic(s);
2. Identifying the diacritics using classes that expose databases of information about Unicode characters, and stripping them out.

Answer (score 0):

Sure its possible if you write out the algorithm yourself.  The only thing close to doing what you speak with the OOB Regex.Match() overloads is in the RegexOptions, the [CultureInvariant.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions(VS.95).aspx)  But, unless you are flipping culture's that's not going to be of any use.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to look into [Soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex)/[Metaphone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphone) functions, to first normalise strings, and then perform your regex operations on the results of that?